# Type inference failure when taking the modulus of a random number

Tags: rust

> rustc 1.0.0-nightly (be9bd7c93 2015-04-05) (built 2015-04-05)

```
extern crate rand;

fn test(a: isize) {
    println!("{}", a);
}

fn main() {
    test(rand::random() % 20)
}
```

this code compiled before Rust beta, but now it doesn't:

```
src/main.rs:8:10: 8:22 error: unable to infer enough type information about `_`; type annotations required [E0282]
src/main.rs:8     test(rand::random() % 20)
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I must write this code to compile:

```
extern crate rand;

fn test(a: isize) {
    println!("{}", a);
}

fn main() {
    test(rand::random::<isize>() % 20)
}
```

How can I make the compiler infer the type?

Comment: also note that you should not be using `random()` and then `% 20` to get a number between `0` and `20`, but a `rand::distributions::Range` (see example http://doc.rust-lang.org/rand/rand/index.html#monte-carlo-estimation-of-%CF%80 ). The issue with using the modulo operator is, that you don't get a truly random distribution. You are instead increasing the probability for small numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler cannot infer the type in this situation, there are too many unknowns.

Let us call `R` the output type of `rand::random()`, and `I` the type of `20`.

The conditions imposed by `test(rand::random() % 20)` are only:

```
R: Rand + Rem<I, Ouput=isize>
I: integral variable (i8, u8, i16, u16, i32, u32, i64, u64, isize or usize)
```

Nothing guaranties that only a single pair `(T, I)` will meet these requirements (and it's actually quite easy to create a new type `T` fulfilling them), thus the compiler cannot choose by itself.

Thus using `rand::random::<isize>()` is the correct approach here.